# Draw contours around objects with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

I'm trying to draw a contour on two overlapping objects. Here I take a photo of two pens.
But it cannot perfectly draw contours. There are some little contours inside. How do I remove it?

Here is my original photo

[image]

and result

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

img = cv2.imread('img/pen001.jpg',1)

img =  cv2.cvtColor(img , cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 102 , 160, 0)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.float32)/10
dst = cv2.filter2D(thresh, -1, kernel)

contour1, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dst, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img , contour1, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3 )
plt.imshow(dst)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a potential approach to obtaining the contours

- Convert image to grayscale and blur image
- Threshold to obtain a binary image
- Find contours
- Iterate through contours and filter using a minimum contour area
- Draw contours

Threshold image

[image]

Find contours

[image]

Notice in this image, the small contours inside the pen and unwanted contours in the paper were detected. Your question was how to remove the small contours inside. There are two solutions to this. One is to use `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` instead of `cv2.RETR_TREE` and the 2nd is to filter out small contours by their area using `cv2.contourArea()`. After making these changes, here's the result

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
blur = cv2.medianBlur(image, 9)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 110 ,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

min_area = 5000
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > min_area:
        cv2.drawContours(image,[c], 0, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: oh, Thank you very much. I understood some things from you.