# How can I create bounding boxes/contour around the outer object only - Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

So I've been trying to make bounding boxes around a couple of fruits that I made in paint. I'm a total beginner to opencv so I watched a couple tutorials and the code that I typed made, makes contours around the object and using that I create bounding boxes. However it makes way too many tiny contours and bounding boxes. For example, heres the initial picture:
[image]

and heres the picture after my code runs:
[image]

However this is what I want:

[image]

Heres my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\bob\Desktop\coursera\coursera-2021\project2\fruits.png')

grayscaled = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayscaled, (7,7), 1)
canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 50)
img1 = img.copy()
all_pics = []

contours, Hierarchy = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*peri, True)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        bob = img [y:y+h, x:x+w]
        all_pics.append((x, bob))
        cv2.rectangle(img1, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
       

cv2.imshow("title", img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **FloodFill** in combination with **FindContours** can help you:

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read original image
dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
im = cv2.imread(dir+'/'+'im.png')

# convert image to Grayscale and Black/White
gry = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/im_1_grayscale.png',gry)
bw=cv2.threshold(gry, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/im_2_black_white.png',bw)

# Use floodfill to identify outer shape of objects
imFlood = bw.copy()
h, w = bw.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
cv2.floodFill(imFlood, mask, (0,0), 0)
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/im_3_floodfill.png',imFlood)

# Combine flood filled image with original objects
imFlood[np.where(bw==0)]=255
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/im_4_mixed_floodfill.png',imFlood)

# Invert output colors
imFlood=~imFlood
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/im_5_inverted_floodfill.png',imFlood)

# Find objects and draw bounding box
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(imFlood, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*peri, True)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    bob = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Save final image
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/im_6_output.png',im)
```

**Grayscale and black/white:**

[image]

**Add flood fill:**

[image]

**Blend original objects with the flood filled version:**

[image]

**Invert the colors of blended version:**

[image]

**Final output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

his guys answer was just what I was looking for. If anyone runs through this problem try this:
[Draw contours around objects with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711662/draw-contours-around-objects-with-opencv)