# Python CV: Detecting a shape made of lines

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image

I have an image that contains shapes made out of lines. I would like to use a Python library (e.g. opencv or skimage) to identify the shapes.

So if the input is this:

[image: input image]

I'm trying to get to an output like this:

[image]

I'm fairly new to CV techniques and have been trying several processing techniques in opencv documentation/tutorials, but haven't found any ideas that can emphasis the angle or clustering of the lines as I imagine I need to solve this problem.

I'm also open to machine learning based approaches to solving this problem but preferably ones that won't require me to generate an especially large dataset.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me but maybe this one can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68780136/how-can-i-create-bounding-boxes-contour-around-the-outer-object-only-python-op/68786047#68786047

Comment: (gaussian blur, then) sobel in x and y direction separately, then you can calculate angles. that's one possible approach. won't be exact near corners and edges. -- finding contours maybe. then you get a bunch of narrow strips. you can then associate them back together by orientation and proximity.

Comment: correction: since there's a line "missing", my second suggestion would have a hard time with the horizontally striped area. best to work with "texture analysis" (the sobel and angle calculation is a simple type of that).

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz. Yeah I figure I ultimately need to focus on the angles. If I could find a group of lines at the same angle and draw a line from one tip to another that would go a long way to solving the "missing" line problem you mention.

Comment: Are the lines within the shapes always horizontal or vertical - or could they be at other angles? How complex could the shapes be - do you have more complicated examples you can share?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect answer, but I've found some success using this Gaussian adaptive thresholding and Harris corner detection.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("input.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,3,0)
img = cv2.cornerHarris(threshold, 35, 1, 0.2)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='binary')
```

[image]

It doesn't solve the problem completely but it manages to separate the shapes in a meaningful way which is a strong start for me.